# Convert an Eigen::TensorMap to Eigen::Tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen, eigen3

It's possible to convert an `Eigen::Map` to a `Matrix` by assignment:

```
vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto m_map = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&v[0]);
Eigen::MatrixXf m = m_map;
cout << m << endl;
```

This produces:

```
 1 2
 3 4
```

If I try to do something similar with a `Tensor`:

```
vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto mapped_t = Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&v[0], 2, 2);
Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> t = mapped_t;
```

I simply get the compiler error `YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE`.  Is there any way to convert a TensorMap to a Tensor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `Eigen::RowMajor` is not the default for `Eigen::Tensor` which means you are not assigning to the same type which means `YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE`.  You  have to explicitly request swapping the layout.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main()
{
  std::vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  auto mapped_t = Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&v[0], 2, 2);
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> t = Eigen::TensorLayoutSwapOp<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(mapped_t);
}
```

Using C++14 you could write a nice instantiator function for that.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

namespace Eigen {
  template < typename T >
  decltype(auto) TensorLayoutSwap(T&& t)
  {
    return Eigen::TensorLayoutSwapOp<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(t);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<float> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  auto mapped_t = Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&v[0], 2, 2);
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> t = Eigen::TensorLayoutSwap(mapped_t);
}
```

Comment: I am getting some error like this: static Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::MapType Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Map(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Scalar*) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<const float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::MapType = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<const float, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Scalar = const float]' cannot be overloaded